# standard geographic tilizing/binning method?

Tags: python, mapping, gis, geodjango, tiling

I'm trying to learn and understand more about mapping and displaying values on a map. (GIS)

At the moment I'M looking to take some values and apply those values to a tile or bin on a map.
Ideally I'd like the tile sizes to be uniform, like 100 meters, 500 meters, etc.

Is there a standard method for creating uniform tile sizes?
Or 
Are what are common accepted method to deal with this kind of data display?

(Currently I'm using geodjango and it's related toolset geos, proj4, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to be working with geospatial raster image formats, where the color of a pixel represents the value for that tile.

The size of a tile (and whether it's uniform) will depend on the projection of your raster.

[GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) is a library for working with geospatial raster formats.